# Configure custom id's with searchkick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

Is it possible to configure searchkick to use custom document id's? I'm considering using it but my app is multi-tenant I need to incorporate the tenant_id with the document id to make it unique system wide.

We're currently doing this by combining it with the record id using a hyphen like so: "RECORD_ID-TENANT_ID" which works great. If I can do this with searchkick I'll try it out.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to answer my own question in case someone else is looking for this in the future.. Custom id's are supported with searchkick by using the "search_document_id" method in the model.